# Weird layout behavior in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have some weird problem going on in my UIPageViewController.
I have a storyboard file with all my UIViewControllers I want to display in my UIPageViewController using this code:

```
func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController! {

    var viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(pageIdentifiers[index] as! String) as! UIViewController
    return viewController

}
```

The pageIdentifiers is an array with Storyboard ID's.

I present my UIPageViewController modally (full screen). My first UIViewController appears without problems. After swiping to the next UIViewController, my views inside that controller move about 20 pixel down... The same is happening for my next ViewControllers. I really have no idea what is causing this issue. I hope you guys have an idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found the answer here!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791183/ios-8-uipageviewcontroller-applying-constraints-after-transitions