# xcode 7 beta 3 swift UIPageViewController subview resizing issue

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller, image-resizing, xcode7-beta3

I followed [the tutorial online](http://shrikar.com/ios-swift-tutorial-uipageviewcontroller-as-user-onboarding-tool/) to test UIPageViewController. Everything ran well in the simulator, but when I tested it in my iphone 5s and iphone 6, the transition looked wired like the gif image. It looks like the subview was resizing after transition. However, if the next/previous image was loaded before, there is no resizing issue. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26216183/4775662). Basically it is a constraint problem. I just changed from base on the layout guide to the view., and everything works well.