# Auto-Layout and PageViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, layout

I have a simple controller with a container, I want to use `UIPageViewController` inside this container however I have a small problem with auto-layout on my child VC.
Here is my storyboard, I have a single label in my left VC which is at the center of the view.
[image]

When I set an embed segue from my container to my left VC I have no issue with label position : 
[image]

However when I set my embed segue to my `EndGamePageViewController` which is supposed to present my left VC I have this issue with auto-layout :

[image]

I have already look at other relative questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791183/ios-8-uipageviewcontroller-applying-constraints-after-transitions), but this does not change anything, I have also tried to add

```
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
```

in the `viewDidLoad` of my left VC but this does not work, if anyone can help me figure this out, this would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: where is `EndGamePageViewController` view in storyboard ?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure to understand, the `EndGamePageViewController` is a subclass of `UIPageViewController` on the right in my storyboard, it's a simple pageviewcontroller which display only twice my left VC.

Comment: do you have any constraints setup for its view ?

Comment: This controller has nothing inside, just the delegate function for the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` and  `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`, it's only used to display my left VC which contains the label centered. You can see that it does not have a `UIView` or something else.