# UIPageViewController with scrollview odd inset bounce

Tags: uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

[Storyboard Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/fjn6w9orv/)

I wonder if anyone can shed any light on this for me.

I have a `UIPageViewController` as part of a `SWRevealViewController` structure as seen in the storyboard in the linked picture.

The `UIPageViewController` contains a series of `UIViewControllers` which have a vertical scroll views in them. The first page shows fine but when I swipe left to display a new page the view loads about 30 pixels to high and after 0.5 a second it drops down to the right place. After that when you scroll left and right it displays normally.

I have tried everything in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202475/content-pushed-down-in-a-uipageviewcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller) so far and nothing has worked.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets  = false;

pageViewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets  = false;
```

I am pretty sure it is something to do with `UIPageViewController` scroll inset but not sure what to do about it as I have tried everything I can think of in the last 3 days to try and fix this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but I had a smaller 5px bounce issue scrolling images in a UIPageViewController. Nothing in the post you look through helped me either. But using a separate UIView as a container view between the individual page view controller's view and my UIImageView miraculously solved the issue for me.

So the hierarchy you want in your page's view controller's view is:

1. Main View
2. Container View
3. Your Actual view content